# Firefox does not run "box-sizing:border-box"?

Tags: html, css

Firefox does not run "box-sizing:border-box" while IE and Chrome is ok? What solution for this?

Comment: *sidenote:* read CSS reference in Mozilla Developer Network (MDN), which provides accurate specs & compatibility of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox supports `box-sizing` through the `-moz` prefix](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box)

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

You can also write this as:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
/* only needed to support very old browsers */
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This will give priority to the non-proprietary `box-sizing` when  Firefox implements it.  Currently, Firefox is the only browser that supports `padding-box`.

Answer (score 1):

use vendor prefix: `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;`

Better way to use like this

```
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; // for older browser
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; // for older browser
box-sizing: border-box;
```